# Changing color of Game Objects in a list at the same time

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, colors

So I have a list full of Game Objects. I want to change their colors at the the same time. The way I'm doing it right now is with 2 for loops changing every Game Object's color one by one but I need it to be updated at the same time. Here's my code

```
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.3f);
        var places = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ground");
            for (int i = 0; i <= GOlist.Count; i++)
            {
                renderer = GOlist[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
                Color c = renderer.material.color;
                for (float s = 0.28f; s <= 1f; s += 0.02f)
                {
                    c.r = s;
                    c.g = s;
                    c.b = s;

                  renderer.color = c;


                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Well don’t tell it to wait in the loop. As it will wait between each one then

Answer (score 0):

Just swap the for loops round...

```
var places = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ground");
for (float s = 0.28f; s <= 1f; s += 0.02f)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= GOlist.Count; i++)
    {
        renderer = GOlist[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        Color c = renderer.material.color;
        c.r = s;
        c.g = s;
        c.b = s;
        renderer.color = c;
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
}
```